# Draw new graph on selection of new variable from drop down menu and/or radio button change

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a data visualisation that draws a new graph each time you choose a new department in a group down menu and you are able to switch between seeing the raw data or overall as a percentage of males/females in the role. I had the graph refreshing each time a new option was chosen but then I added the radio buttons and had to switch everything up. Now it only draws a new graph when the radio button is changed. How can I get the graph to refresh for a change of radio button OR a new option chosen in the menu (and current radio button selection remain)?

Here are some of the relevant sections of my code:

```
<p>Select department: <select id="opts">
      <option hidden>-- Select University Department --</option>
      <optgroup label="University of Auckland">
        <option value="UoABiology">Biology</option>
        <option value="UoAChemistry">Chemistry</option>
      </optgroup></select>
</p>

<p>
      <input name="mode" type="radio" value="raw" id="raw" ><label for="data-raw"> Raw data</label>
      <input name="mode" type="radio" value="percent" id="percent" ><label for="data-percent"> Percentage</label>
    </p>

<script>
var UoABiology = [
        {group: 'Research Fellow', male: 0, female: 0},
        {group: 'Lecturer', male: 21, female: 9},
        {group: 'Associate Professor', male: 16, female: 7},
        {group: 'Professor', male: 19, female: 4},
        {group: 'Emeritus Professor', male: 1, female: 0}
      ];
      var UoAChemistry = [
        {group: 'Research Fellow', male: 2, female: 1},
        {group: 'Lecturer', male: 11, female: 1},
        {group: 'Associate Professor', male: 6, female: 1},
        {group: 'Professor', male: 9, female: 4},
        {group: 'Emeritus Professor', male: 2, female: 0}
      ];

function updateraw(exampleData) {
      var maxValue = Math.max(
        d3.max(exampleData, function(d) { return d.male; }),
        d3.max(exampleData, function(d) { return d.female; })
      );

      svg.append("text")
          .attr("x", (w/2)) 
          .attr("y", "-11px")            
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
          .style("font-size", "18px") 
          .text("Career Progression in "+ "University Departments" +"");

      var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxValue])
        .range([0, regionWidth])
        .nice();

      var xScaleLeft = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxValue])
        .range([regionWidth, 0]);

      var xScaleRight = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxValue])
        .range([0, regionWidth]);

      var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(exampleData.map(function(d) { return d.group; }))
        .rangeRoundBands([h,0], 0.1);

      var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('right')
        .tickSize(4,0)
        .tickPadding(margin.middle-4);

      var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left')
        .tickSize(4,0)
        .tickFormat('');

      var xAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));

      var xAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale.copy().range([pointA, 0]))
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickFormat(d3.format("d"));

      var leftBarGroup = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointA, 0) + 'scale(-1,1)');
      var rightBarGroup = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointB, 0));

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis y left')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointA, 0))
        .call(yAxisLeft)
        .selectAll('text')
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle');

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis y right')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointB, 0))
        .call(yAxisRight);

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis x left')
        .attr('transform', translation(0, h))
        .call(xAxisLeft);

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis x right')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointB, h))
        .call(xAxisRight);

      leftBarGroup.selectAll('.bar.left')
        .data(exampleData)
        .enter().append('rect')
          .attr('class', 'bar left')
          .attr('x', 0)
          .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.group); })
          .attr('width', function(d) { return xScale(d.male); })
          .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
          .on('mouseover', tipM.show)
          .on('mouseout', tipM.hide);

      rightBarGroup.selectAll('.bar.right')
        .data(exampleData)
        .enter().append('rect')
          .attr('class', 'bar right')
          .attr('x', 0)
          .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.group); })
          .attr('width', function(d) { return xScale(d.female); })
          .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
          .on('mouseover', tipF.show)
          .on('mouseout', tipF.hide);
    };

    function updatepercent(exampleData) {
      var maxValue = Math.max(
        d3.max(exampleData, function(d) { return (1); }),
        d3.max(exampleData, function(d) { return (1); })
      );

      svg.append("text")
          .attr("x", (w/2)) 
          .attr("y", "-11px")            
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")  
          .style("font-size", "18px") 
          .text("Career Progression in "+ "University Departments" +"");

      var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxValue])
        .range([0, regionWidth])
        .nice();

      var xScaleLeft = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxValue])
        .range([regionWidth, 0]);

      var xScaleRight = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, maxValue])
        .range([0, regionWidth]);

      var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(exampleData.map(function(d) { return d.group; }))
        .rangeRoundBands([h,0], 0.1);

      var yAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('right')
        .tickSize(4,0)
        .tickPadding(margin.middle-4);

      var yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left')
        .tickSize(4,0)
        .tickFormat('');

      var xAxisRight = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickFormat(d3.format("%"));

      var xAxisLeft = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale.copy().range([pointA, 0]))
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickFormat(d3.format("%"));

      var leftBarGroup = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointA, 0) + 'scale(-1,1)');
      var rightBarGroup = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointB, 0));

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis y left')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointA, 0))
        .call(yAxisLeft)
        .selectAll('text')
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle');

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis y right')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointB, 0))
        .call(yAxisRight);

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis x left')
        .attr('transform', translation(0, h))
        .call(xAxisLeft);

      svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis x right')
        .attr('transform', translation(pointB, h))
        .call(xAxisRight);

      leftBarGroup.selectAll('.bar.left')
        .data(exampleData)
        .enter().append('rect')
          .attr('class', 'bar left')
          .attr('x', 0)
          .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.group); })
          .attr('width', function(d) { return xScale(d.male/Math.max(d.male+d.female,0.1)); })
          .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
          .on('mouseover', tipMpercent.show)
          .on('mouseout', tipMpercent.hide);;

      rightBarGroup.selectAll('.bar.right')
        .data(exampleData)
        .enter().append('rect')
          .attr('class', 'bar right')
          .attr('x', 0)
          .attr('y', function(d) { return yScale(d.group); })
          .attr('width', function(d) { return xScale(d.female/Math.max(d.male+d.female,0.1)); })
          .attr('height', yScale.rangeBand())
          .on('mouseover', tipFpercent.show)
          .on('mouseout', tipFpercent.hide);;
    };
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="mode"]');

    function radiobutton() {
     if ( this.value === 'raw' ) {
        var exampleData = eval(d3.select('#opts').property('value'));
        svg.selectAll('*').remove();
        updateraw(exampleData);} 
     else if ( this.value === 'percent' ) {
        var exampleData = eval(d3.select('#opts').property('value'));
        svg.selectAll('*').remove();
        updatepercent(exampleData);}  
    }

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
       radio.addEventListener('change', radiobutton);
    });

//THIS IS WHAT I USED TO HAVE TO CHANGE THE GRAPH ON NEW DROP DOWN MENU SELECTION


 /* d3.select('#opts')
        .on('change', function() {
        var exampleData = eval(d3.select(this).property('value'));
        svg.selectAll('*').remove();
        updatepercent(exampleData)}); */
    </script>
```

Comment: Does it work if you uncomment your previous code ? I think there's no conflict between the radio event listener and the dropdown listener.

Comment: No because I need it to know if it should be calling updateraw() or updatepercent()

Answer (score 0):

I'd create one update method that you call for all the events (radios and menu change events) then in that new update method get the value of the currently selected radio button and based on that value call the appropriate updateraw or updatepercent methods. 
something like the following un-tested pseudo code

```
//setup event listeners - preferably using consistent selection methods (either vanilla js or using d3 but not mixed)
Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
   radio.addEventListener('change', myGenericUpdateEvent);
});

d3.select('#opts').on('change', myGenericUpdateEvent);

function myGenericUpdateEvent() {
    var selectedRadio = document.querySelector('input[type=radio][name="mode"][checked]');
    if ( selectedRadio.value === 'raw' ) {
       //do the updateraw thing
    } else {
       //do the other thing
    }
}
```